# How to broadcast event between two controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two controllers and try to send an event by using below code from controller A:

```
$scope.$watch("showContextFooter", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('contextFooterChange', {isOpen: $scope.showContextFooter});
    });
```

in controller B i am trying to catch this event by this way:

```
$rootScope.$on('contextFooterChange', function(data){
        $log.info(data);
    });

//OR

    $scope.$on("$destroy",$scope.$on("contextFooterChange", function (e) {
        $log.info(e);
    }));
```

but not getting any event in controller B. i try to debug and see that controller A broadcasting but nothing happen in controller B. Can some one give me hint.

Comment: Try to broadcast outside `$watch`. Does it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.$on('contextFooterChange', function(data){
    $log.info(data);
});
```

`$rootScope.$broadcast` sends event to the child scopes so you need to catch on `$scope` level.

IF you want to get in on `$rootScope` level, use `$rootScope.$emit` rather than `$rootScope.$broadcast` (which I would strongly suggest because of performance boosts)

Answer (score 0):

The `$on` event watcher yields two arguments; `event` and `data`:

```
̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶'̶c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶F̶o̶o̶t̶e̶r̶C̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶{̶  
$scope.$on('contextFooterChange', function(event,data){
    $log.info(data);
});
```

Also it is better to place the `$on` watcher on `$scope`, then it will be automatically destroyed when its `$scope` is destroyed.

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrlA", function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch("showContextFooter", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.$root.$broadcast('contextFooterChange', {isOpen: $scope.showContextFooter});
    });
})
.controller("ctrlB", function($scope,$log) {
    $scope.$on('contextFooterChange', function(event,data){
        $scope.message = data;
        $log.info(data);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlA">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showContextFooter">showContextFooter<br>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
        message={{message}}
    </div>
</body>
```